# ScrollView Nativescript in Android with button/label inside is not triggering the tap event most of the time

Tags: android, scrollview, nativescript

has anyone experienced an unusual behavior using scroll-view with button inside in android (nativescript). Sometimes the tap event won't trigger. I used the scrollview to create a menu. Below is my html code.

Comment: If the scroll view is moving at all the tap won't execute, native behavior so no bug there. The first tap is likely 'stopping' the movement of the scrollview and then you are able to get the inside view components (buttons) their tap events.

Comment: got it.. thank you!

Comment: hi @BradMartin another thing, this is the behavior i'm getting: 
i have 4 button inside the scrollview and i offset the scroll depending on the location of the button. if i clicked the 2nd button, i can easily click the 3rd and 4th, but having a hard time getting the event for the 1st button. and then same story if i clicked the 3rd and 4th button. is it also because of the movement of the scrollview?

Comment: Not certain to be honest. Seems like a strange issue, I would throw a demo on a repo and file an issue on the NativeScript repo so the team can test and see if there's a bug somewhere or if it's expected.